# UV Distortion on Helicopter

Tags: uv

I'm currently modelling a low polygonal model for a game and just finished unwrapping and organizing my uv map. I'm not very knowledgeable about uv mapping, so I was wondering if the distortion in these screen shots is acceptable enough to move on to texturing.

As you can see, I mirrored the chopper down the middle to conserve space, but it seems that there's some distortion around the center areas. Is it okay to leave it as is or is there something I should do to fix this? [image]

Comment: That looks nicely done, Go ahead and texture it. When you're finished, show us the results in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm)

Comment: Basically the only way to tell if it's unwrapped sufficiently is to give it a texture and see how you like it!

Comment: Try to make sure that the polygons are planer before unwrapping, this will reduce stretching.  You can also fix this after and then adjust the UV Coordinates in the UV Image Editor.  Some stretching is unavoidable for curved surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

as long as no complex *textures* need to be there (and they shouldn't if  you want to be able to see from the cockpit) it should be perfectly acceptable to have a material that is basically uniform.

> Disclaimer; I've been called sloppy on this before, but never had bad results.

Answer (score 1):

The UVs are ok. Depends how much time you are willing to spend on them.

- You would like the checker pattern to be mostly squares
- The squares should be same size everywhere
- The UV seams should be on least visible places

You can improve on the second point and also reconsider if there is better placement for the seam on the cabin. If there will be text on the heli the mirrored UVs will not work on the hull and so the cabin could have 1 UV island then.

Comment: I believe the cabin seam is because he is using a mirror modifier.  I don't know for sure but it is a pretty good guess.